# How to identify which processes are using the GPU?

Tags: windows, gpu

I have Nvidia GT750M in a laptop, with "display GPU activity icon in notification area" activated.

Right now all I have open are Google Chrome, Notepad++, and windows explorer, yet it says 2 processes are using the GPU.

How do I find out WHICH processes are using the GPU without installing extra software?

Comment: Process Explorer shows GPU activity on a per-process basis, but its not sortable, so you have to select a process and look at its properties to see what GPU impact it has (if any) but once you find the process, you can view its GPU usage and VRAM usage ( dedicated, shared and committed). https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer Process explorer does not require installation, but will have to be downloaded from microsoft.

Comment: Not possible to see what process using GPU without installing extra software?

Comment: Not in Win7 or older. not sure about Win8+. you could check the resource monitor on them, but on win7, it does not show GPU stats. GPU information has historically be vendor-specific so at least until recent years, you could only rely on utilities from NVidia or ATI/AMD or their resalers.

Comment: This most likely will never be a feature of Windows not all systems have a GPU worth reporting this information or perhaps most users don't care or wouldn't know what it was

Comment: Is the GT750M the only GPU in your system? No integrated graphics such as Intel HD 4500?

Comment: Note, you are already using extra software "display GPU activity icon in notification area" is not part of windows but is part of some other software you have installed.

Answer (score 4):

Since I don't have 50 reputation to respond to [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1022814/how-to-identify-which-processes-are-using-the-gpu#comment1422136_1022814) by [Frank Thomas](https://superuser.com/users/171793/frank-thomas), apparently creating this answer is the only way I can contribute to the conversation.

Here's how to use Process Explorer to sort your apps by VRAM usage.

1. Download Process Explorer from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer
2. Once you've opened the app, either click View > Select Columns, or right click any column header and then click Select Columns.
3. In the window that pops up, go to the Process GPU tab. Enable whatever stats you want to monitor ('GPU Usage' is a percentage, the rest are byte values), and click OK.
4. Left click any column header to sort by that column.

Comment: You cant comment because you are not trusted yet. You shouldnt abuse your privileges.  However, this looks like an answer  so plus one

Answer (score 1):

You can use tool Sysinternals Process Explorer. You can download it from Microsoft website.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer
It kind of is extra software, but you download it from Microsoft website, not from some unknown company website. So it's more like extra update form windows. :)

After you run it go to "view -> select columns -> Process GPU" and check "GPU Usage".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

tick the item shown on the nvidia control panel. then click the tray icon